# SQL User Defined Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I am currently working with User Defined Functions and having a hard time grasping the concept around how the function accepts one parameter and returns another one.

I have a table that has Employee ID and Log IDs.  The UDF should accepts the EmployeeID and returns UserLoginID.  The UserLoginID is the last part of the LogID column after the '\'. I need to return the entire column from the table.

Table Example

```
EmployeeID   LoginId
1    database\userid1
2    database\userid2
3    database\userid3
```

UDF query 1:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fx_IDtest]
(@EmployeeID int)

RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @UserID nvarchar(50)
SET @UserID = (SELECT SUBSTRING(LoginID,CHARINDEX('\',LoginID)+1, LEN(LoginID)) 
            FROM HumanResources.Employee
            WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
            )
RETURN @UserID
END
```

UDF query 2:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fx_IDtest2] 
(@EmployeeID int)

RETURNS table
AS
RETURN
(SELECT SUBSTRING(LoginID,CHARINDEX('\',LoginID)+1, LEN(LoginID)) as USERID
            FROM HumanResources.Employee
            WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
            )
```

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing versus what you're expecting?

Comment: Also, how are you calling the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI... Your first function is fine, and does exactly what I believe you want... I think perhaps you're not calling the function correctly.

I tested it as follows...

```
/*
CREATE TABLE testDATA (EmployeeID int, LoginID nvarchar(50))

insert into testDATA
select 1,    'database\userid1' union
select 2,    'database\userid2' union
select 3,    'database\userid3'

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fx_IDtest
(@EmployeeID int)

RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @UserID nvarchar(50)
SET @UserID = (SELECT SUBSTRING(LoginID,CHARINDEX('\',LoginID)+1, LEN(LoginID)) 
            FROM testDATA
            WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
            )
RETURN @UserID
END
*/

SELECT *, dbo.fx_IDtest(EmployeeID)
FROM testDATA
WHERE EmployeeID = 1

SELECT dbo.fx_IDtest(1)
```

Both select statements, give me `userid1` as a return.

Notice, that you must provide the schema for UDF's in your `SELECT`, this is often overlooked.  You cannot do `SELECT fx_IDtest(1)` instead you must do `SELECT dbo.fx_IDtest(1)`

Comment: JiggsJedi -- Thank you for your feedback.  I had been toiling over this for days.